# Ubuntu Server apt-get upgrade - will it downgrade PHP?

Tags: ubuntu, php5

I have PHP 5.3 installed on an Ubuntu Server using the Debian packages.

I've just run the commands `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` - the latter wishes to upgrade certain PHP5 related packages "without verification".

If I let it, will this downgrade my PHP 5.3 installation down to PHP 5.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I let it, will this downgrade my PHP 5.3 installation down to PHP 5.2?
>   No, because the installed version is newer. You may hold packages:

```
sudo echo "package_name" hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```